# How to Integrate node module with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, node-modules

I'm developing a google chrome extension that needs some node modules in order to run. These modules have been downloaded with npm.

Comment: It depends on the context you want to use them in (background script, content script, pop-up, etc.) but you could simply just import them, ex: `import Module from 'path/moduleName'` in most contexts.

Comment: if i do in this way i receive the the following error: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` The file i want to load is a .tm file

Comment: You've probably got the file's path wrong. Also, you may have to set those files as web accessible, here is the documentation for that https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources this all depends on the context.

Comment: thank you very much but if i type `node_modules/*` within `web_accessible_resources` i receive this error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: You can't `import` modules in a content script. You can use [scriptTagContext](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext) library that will allow you to use `require`-type modules.

Comment: thank you but I didn't understand how to use it in order to load the node modules.

Comment: i solved by using this: [chrome-extension-skeleton](https://github.com/salsita/chrome-extension-skeleton)